# How to remove items that show up as substring later in file?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Given some file that has,

```
foo/bar
foo/bar/gaz
foo/bar/urk
hello/world
hello/world/congress
hello/world/united/states
hello/world
```

How can I remove lines which have previous lines as substrings?

For example, `foo/bar/gaz` has `foo/bar` - a previous line - as substring, and should be removed.

The above list should be reduced to,

```
foo/bar
hello/world
```

(This is kind of like common denominator for lines in a file)

Comment: Would `foo/bar` be considered a substring of `bobfoo/barsue`?

Comment: Do you also want to delete lines thar has a following line as a substring? When the last line was `hello`, should `hello/world` be removed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`.

```
awk '{for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) next} {a[$0]}1' file
```

Output:

```
foo/bar
hello/world
```

Comment: Good code.  We did interpret the OP's goals differently.   Perhaps the OP can clarify.

Comment: @John1024 OP says `have previous lines as substrings`. But yes, could possibly mean `AND starts with this substring` while haven't said that yet, but input file is like that. The first case is a superset of the second, but checking only for the second could be faster for cases it matters (large input). Anyway, we are open to modifications. Good code also yours, cheers.

Comment: In case we consider the substring only at the beginning, modify condition to `if ($0 ~ "^"i)`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk '{for (s in a) if (s == substr($0,1,length(s))) next; print; a[$0]}' file
foo/bar
hello/world
```

The previous lines, excluding the those that are substrings of other lines, are the keys of array `a`.  `for (s in a) if (s == substr($0,1,length(s))) next` checks to see if the current line, `$0`, is a substring of a previous line.  If so, we skip this line and jump to the `next` line.

If the current line is not a substring of a previous line, then we `print` it and add it as a key of `a`.

#### Another example

```
$ cat file2
/etc
/foo/bar/etc
$ awk '{for (s in a) if (s == substr($0,1,length(s))) next; print; a[$0]}' file2
/etc
/foo/bar/etc
```

The code in this answer treats the "common denominator" as starting from the beginning of the string.  Thus `/etc` is not a "common denominator" for `/foo/bar/etc` even though both have the common substring `/etc`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'G;/^([^\n]+).*\n\1(\n.*)*$/d;h;P;d' file
```

Stuff unique lines in the hold space and delete lines that partialy/fully match those lines.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a line `foo/bar`, you want to delete everything with `foo/bar.`.
Just add a dot to every line and use that for the exclusion list.

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/$/./' file) file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` that may be faster if your file is larger:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="/" } 
                $0 in arr { next }
                {   s=$1
                    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
                        if (s in arr || (s OFS $i) in arr) next
                        s=s OFS $i}
                    arr[$0]} 1' file
```

Instead of looping over the entire array contents for each line of input, this loops over the substrings of each line and tests that for presence in the array of previous substrings.